# Yii2 mysql request error with "Call to a member function getCount() on array"

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

am very new to Yii2 but seems a nice framework. i tryed it out and also used the GII autocreator to generate my CRUDs. For testing, i wanted to create a recipe database. 
Gii created nice CRUDs and everything works fine ... when i only use IDs in the listing. For this i wanted to create my own SQL Statement but i always run into the error **"Call to a member function getCount() on array"**.
i just figured out that yii2 want to have a **count** of the records in this array, and i tried "->count("*")" also in the statement. I had similar error, but as "string" not as "array". 
I searched a lot on google, but i couldnt find any good solution. thats why i tried to ask here.
I have 3 tables which should be linked.

here is my statement in the Controller

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new IngredientsSearch();
        //$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams); #Created with Gii and works fine


        $dataProvider = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['recipes.title', 'ingredientslist.name', 'quantities.shortname', 'ingredients.amount'])
            ->from('ingredients')
            ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'ingredientslist', 'ingredients.ingredientslist_id = ingredientslist.id')
            ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'recipes', 'ingredients.recipe_id = recipes.id')
            ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'quantities', 'ingredients.quantity_id = quantities.id')
            ->limit(20)
            ->all();


        /*
         * >> Working Statement from DB
         * SELECT l.name, r.title, q.shortname, i.amount FROM `ingredients` as i
         * LEFT JOIN ingredientslist as l ON i.ingredientslist_id = l.id
         * LEFT JOIN recipes as r ON i.recipe_id = r.id
         * LEFT JOIN quantities as q ON i.quantity_id = q.id
         *
        */

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

if it helps:

- the ingredientslist have all ingredients which exists in all recipes (name, shortname, source, ...)
- the recipes is the table with the recipe itself (title, description, workingtime, ...)
- the quantities is the table with used quantity (like kg, ml, ...)
- the ingredients is the table with the infos combined of the ingredients (amount of quantities like 2pc eggs)

Or is there another way to solve this problem, maybe with an ORM in Yii2, or automated sql creator or something which i did not yet found?
hope someone can help me with that!

best
cyperfax

Answer (score 1):

in dataProvider  you should not use the all() function  .. but only the code for sql query

```
$dataProvider = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['recipes.title', 'ingredientslist.name', 'quantities.shortname', 'ingredients.amount'])
        ->from('ingredients')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'ingredientslist', 'ingredients.ingredientslist_id = ingredientslist.id')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'recipes', 'ingredients.recipe_id = recipes.id')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'quantities', 'ingredients.quantity_id = quantities.id');
```

the all() function perform the real query but in DataProvider this is delegated  to internal method primarly for pagination

and  you should  also avoid limit() because you can manage pagination directly configuring the dataProvider

the count() function  (that failes in you case)  is managed directly by the dataProvider .. enwrapping the query as a subquery and calculating the count for this subquery..

Comment: hi @scaisEdge, thank you for the tip. i changed the code to this you wrote me and the dataprovider query looks like yours. But now yii2 write another error: "Calling unknown method: yii\db\Query::getCount()". Can it be, that the codegeneration with GII is a part of the problem? i also do not understand why yii2 cant find the getCount method now, and before i had an error in it?!?

Comment: Is  not a problem related  to GII . you problem is related  to the fact you are build a sqlDataProvider  (using custom code)  while GII build an ActiveDataProvider  directly by model .. you shoudl take a look  at https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-providers  ..as you can see the sql data provider assign also the count property.. so for you goal you could or add the relation to otherstable in a model  or add the code for count in you dataProvider assignment

Answer (score 0):

thanks to scaisEdge. 
I found a solution to generate fast, good working relational  CRUD.
Big Thank also to the [Krajee Yii Extensions](https://demos.krajee.com/) more detailed the [yii2 enhanced gii](https://github.com/mootensai/yii2-enhanced-gii) from them.
Well, i had some trouble using this module, but after checking the installation from
the required modules and reinstalled them via composer they are working great. 
I have now a full relational crud for recipes with ingredients, sources, images, users, ratings, and some more within 20 minutes of work.
I love this modules!
for someone who want use this also, in the following i describe my installation and what i had to do as workaround for this module for my stuff. Maybe someone need this:

- create tables with all fields i need
- create the relations between the tables
- installed the yii2 enhanced gii via composer (described on github)
- added the neccessary stuff into config/web.php (if "module" is not existing, then you have to create it:

```
'modules' => [
        'gridview' =>  [
            'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module'
            // enter optional module parameters below - only if you need to
            // use your own export download action or custom translation
            // message source
            // 'downloadAction' => 'gridview/export/download',
            // 'i18n' => []
        ],
        'datecontrol' => [
            'class' => '\kartik\datecontrol\Module',
            // see settings on http://demos.krajee.com/datecontrol#module
        ],
        // If you use tree table
        'treemanager' =>  [
            'class' => '\kartik\tree\Module',
            // see settings on http://demos.krajee.com/tree-manager#module
        ]
    ]
```

- here i had my first problem, cause the gridview was not found, then i reinstalled the extension, and if also installed all suggestions from composer which i should install.
- then the 2nd problem was the datepicker, so in reinstalled datepicker also as described in the module help (see link)
- the 3rd problem was that the generation of my models and controllers counldnt find the relation models. So i deleted everything and started with the tables where i dont have any relations, like users, quantities, ingredients tables. Then i created the Cruds where i had the relations like recipes, history, ratings tables.
  [Image to the settings i used in the i/o extension from krajee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erKKD.jpg)
- then i added some menu elements in the index view so that i can edit and manage the cruds easyly. 

  i hope if someone have a similar problem, my description can help a bit. for me, i just can say, the suggest from scaisEdge help me finding this...

Best,
Cyperfax